# Compiled Expression slower than Reflection

Tags: c#, performance, expression-trees

I have a PropertyInfo.SetValue that has a dynamic set. Meaning the value to be set is not known.

I've have a method like this i got from the internet.

```
private static Action<object, object> CreateSetAccess(MethodInfo method)
{
    var obj = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "o");
    var value = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));

    Expression<Action<object, object>> expr =
        Expression.Lambda<Action<object, object>>(
            Expression.Call(
                Expression.Convert(obj, method.DeclaringType),
                method,
                Expression.Convert(value, method.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType)),
            obj,
            value);

    return expr.Compile();
}
```

What this does is create a expression and compile it, but the objects get converted using the parameter types.

I consume it like this.

```
var method2 = CreateSetAccess(property.GetSetMethod());
method2(response, valueToSet);
```

What happens is that this seems to be slower that the `PropertyInfo.SetValue`

Here is my benchmark

```
var xpathNavigator = XmlHelper.CreateXPathDocument(serviceResponse).CreateNavigator();
foreach (var propertyInformation in propertyInformationSource)
{
    // Gets the node using the NodePath provided in the Attribute
    var attr = propertyInformation.Value;
    var pathValue = xpathNavigator.SelectSingleNode(attr.NodePath);
    if (pathValue == null)
        continue;

    object valueToSet = null;
    var property = propertyInformation.Key;

    if (propertyInformation.Value.ShouldDeserialize)
        valueToSet = serializationHelper.Deserialize(property.PropertyType, pathValue.OuterXml, attr.CustomRoot);
    else
        valueToSet = Convert.ChangeType(pathValue.Value, property.PropertyType);

    // this line is only added for the testing for it to be JITd
    var method = CreateSetAccess(property.GetSetMethod());
    method(response, valueToSet);
    property.SetValue(response, valueToSet);
    // end

    TimeSpan fastSet, setValue;

    const int COUNT = 100000;
    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
    {
        var method2 = CreateSetAccess(property.GetSetMethod());
        method2(response, valueToSet);
    }
    watch.Stop();

    fastSet = watch.Elapsed; // result {00:00:08.8500760}

    watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
    {
        property.SetValue(response, valueToSet);
    }
    watch.Stop();

    setValue = watch.Elapsed; // result {00:00:00.0263953}
}
```

I'm wondering why this happens? I'm guessing because I'm always **creating** a new expression, but how can i make it **not** create a new object and make it get cached?

Comment: Not sure what I am missing, but why won't you put the `var method2 =`assignment out of for loop?

Comment: If you call `CreateSetAccess` in the loop, that means that you are compiling the expression 100000 times.

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa because i'ts only used for the test. What will really happen is on the loop, the methodinfo will change, ill attach an update to better visualize

Comment: If compiling a fresh expression each time was faster then the Reflection API would just do this internally. Therefore, it is not. This technique only works if you reuse the same compiled code many times.

Comment: @usr so there is no way to make the expression adjust at runtime based on the methodinfo supplied?

Comment: Reflection does this and that's what's making it so slow. Keep a cache of compiled methods. Use a search engine pointed at SO to see how that's done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If compiling a fresh expression each time was faster then the Reflection API would just do this internally. Therefore, it is not. This technique only works if you reuse the same compiled code many times.

> so there is no way to make the expression adjust at runtime based on the methodinfo supplied?

Reflection does this and that's what's making it so slow. Keep a cache of compiled methods. For example in a `Dictionary<MethodInfo, Action<object, object>>` with a suitable [comparer](https://ayende.com/blog/2658/method-equality).

Comment: Is `MethodInfo` guaranteed to be equal to other instances referring to the same method? I seem to recall it is not. The method presented here suggests the same: https://ayende.com/blog/2658/method-equality

Comment: Yes, turns out it's not which is terrible. This has been discussed on GitHub as well. @Timo

Answer (score 0):

Create `Dictionary<MethodInfo, Action<object, object>> actions` field in your class.
You can remove the static modifier from CreateSetAccess. And then add the following code in it:

```
    Action<object, object> action = null;
    if(actions.TryGetValue(method, out action))
    {
      return action;
    }
     var obj = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "o");
        var value = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));

        Expression<Action<object, object>> expr =
            Expression.Lambda<Action<object, object>>(
                Expression.Call(
                    Expression.Convert(obj, method.DeclaringType),
                    method,
                    Expression.Convert(value, method.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType)),
                obj,
                value);
    expr.Compile();

    cache.Add(method, expr);

    return expr;
}
```